# PostgreSql delete time exceeded

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple PostgreSQL table with a Primary Key named id and around 20 entries.

The following takes between 60 and 70 seconds to execute.

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE id = '20'
```

Simple `SELECT` queries execute in less than 10 mls which is fine.

When running `EXPLAIN` over the `DELETE` query this is the output:

```
"Seq Scan on user  (cost=0.00..1.26 rows=1 width=6)"
"  Filter: ((id)::text = '20'::text)"
```

I cannot find any explanation for those delete query taking that long. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you check pg_locks for locks on this record?

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes.. there aren't any

Comment: First guess: unindexed foreign key referencing user from a large table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One probable cause is that you have a foreign key referencing this table that doesn't have an usable index on the foreign key expression. Because you said that the type of the primary key is irregular the likely cause is that the type of the foreign key doesn't match the type of the primary key.

Edit: I didn't notice at first that your table is so small that the sequential scan is normal.